# Antd calendar does not rerender on state change

Tags: reactjs, antd

Antd calender notices are not re rendered even though valued bound to the date cell render method are changed in the state.

```
<Calendar className="p-48 pt-64" 
     validRange={[this.state.firstDayOfYear, this.state.lastDayOfYear]}
          onPanelChange={this.onPanelChange} onSelect={this.onSelect} 
            dateCellRender={this.dateCellRender} monthCellRender={this.monthCellRender} />
```

`dateCellRender` method:

```
dateCellRender(value) {
    //console.log('dateCellRender',value.date(),value.month(),value.year());
    let listData = this.getListData(value.year() + "-" + String(parseInt(value.month()) + 1) + "-" + value.date());
    return (
        <ul className="events">
            {
                listData.map(item => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        <div onClick={console.log('item')} style={this.dayColorStyle(item.color)}> {item.content} {item.isWholeDay ? '(Full day)' : "(" + item.from + "-" + item.to + ")"}</div>
                    </li>
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    );

}
```

`getListData` function

```
getListData(value) {
    var date = moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    //console.log('getListData',date);

    let listData = [];
    if (this.state.holidaysOfYear[date]) {
        this.state.holidaysOfYear[date].forEach(function (element) {
            let listElement = {
                id: element.ID_HOLIDAY_POLICY,
                content: element.POLICY_NAME,
                type: 'success',
                color: element.COLOR,
                isWholeDay: element.IS_WHOLE_DAY,
                from: element.FROM_TIME,
                to: element.TO_TIME
            };
            listData.push(listElement);
        });
    }
    //console.log('listData',listData);
    return listData;
}
```

when I `setState` `holidaysOfYear` calendar is not re-rendered.

Comment: Have you tried calling [forceUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) after setState?

Comment: yes. it didn't work

Comment: Instead of calling this.state.holidaysOfYear in the getListData function, have you tried passing it in as a prop on Calendar? That way react sees that a prop on the calendar changed and might update it? So it'd be like <Calendar... dateCellRender={(value) => this.dateCellRender(value, this.state.holidaysOfYear)}>

Comment: Will give it a try

Comment: Did not fix by that too. What usually causes something like this? is it shouldComponentUpdate in calendar component?

Comment: I believe so. You could try to set the [renders to highlight using chrome dev tools](https://blog.logrocket.com/make-react-fast-again-part-3-highlighting-component-updates-6119e45e6833) and try and debug from there

Comment: is there a possibility for it to re render if i wrap calendar around a component and pass state through the props?